# Saving a file in neovim messes up the indentation?

Tags: html, vim, neovim

[image: Screenshot side by side Neovim-Vim]

tldr; saving a HTML file in neovim messed up my indentations. Neovim on the left, vim on the right of screenshot.

I just installed neovim with NVchad set up. I've been using it happily for this HTML coding assignment. Link to NVchad here:
https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad

I noticed the indentations were off when I uploaded the file to github. You can see that the  and  tag is messed up. There are a few more examples sprinkled throughout the code.

Is this normal? I am going to edit the file on vim so that the indents are right, but if this is a daily occurence on neovim I will need to go back to just using vim.

Alternatively, is there a plug and play set up for neovim that is focused on python coding? I am only doing HTML as a short course.

What I tried:
I tried to make an HTML file with indents.

What I was expecting:
I expected the indents to stay the same as shown in the neovim file.

What I got:
The indents got messed up.

Comment: This might also be a question for [vi stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: well firstly try to close meta tags properly by ending them with `/>`. Secondly if you start with a preconfigured nvim, we will have a hard time to know what the cause is. Start your vim and nvim with `-u NONE` and then activate the ft stuff by inserting `:filetype plugin indent on` and `:set ft=html` and have a look how it behaves now.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo The [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. This is also true of every other self-closing HTML tag.

Comment: @Rob thanks for stepping in, I did indeed word it badly. My main point is, that I am wondering if this may help and not if it is correctly or not.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo It wouldn't help because browsers are instructed by the standard to ignore such things because it has no meaning and does nothing in HTML.

Comment: @Rob yes of course, but it may change the behaviour of the vim indent plugin.

Comment: Then the plugin developer needs to learn the HTML standard. I question his knowledge of the subject. And if he can't get HTML right, what else does he get wrong?